# Having trouble to autocomplete and auto import while developing on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I've installed latest VSCode on Windows.
Then I installed languaje support for TypeScript
And finally, set some editor options and installed some extensions.

Editor config:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "editor.find.autoFindInSelection": true,
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    },
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro"
}
```

Extensions:
Angular Language Service 0.1.7
Angular V5 Snippets 2.11.2
Auto Import 1.5.3
Debugger for Chrome 4.0.0
TSLint 1.0.24
And some icon/theme

My problem is that I cannot get the modules list when typing some imports in the app.module.ts file for example.

What would you suggest me to do?

Thanks

[image: Suggestion list is not shown]

[image: Shows nothing]

Comment: Auto import is now a default feature in VS code. Try turning off `Auto Import 1.5.3 ` in your extension.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks @Ringo . If you could post that as answer, so I can mark as solved... thanks

Comment: @Ringo I don't have any `Auto Import 1.5.3` dependency. Infact I have only `live server` extension. Still I can't import `HttpClientModule` by mentioning it in `imports[]` array. My vs code / angular versions are up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto import is now a default feature in VS code!

Try turning off Auto Import 1.5.3 in your extension and restart vs code.