# can not do auto imports by merely mentioning them in imports array in angular environment in vs code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I was trying to import very main module `HttpClientModule` in module.ts file. I was hoping it to get auto import if I just mention this under imports array. But I was surprise to know it does not give any auto complete suggestions. Illustration pic below:

[image]

I have the latest versions installed of `vs code` editor and `angular` environment. I have no other extension installed except Ritwick Dey's `live server`. I have gone through internet but couldn't help myself. I reached here : [Having trouble to autocomplete and auto import while developing on Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214123/having-trouble-to-autocomplete-and-auto-import-while-developing-on-angular) solution here says that auto imports are now `vscode` default feature.

But they don't seem to be default in my case.

Lastly I did `npm update` also. But it also couldn't solve the issue.

Because I am new to `angular`... I was just thinking do I have to remember/cram all import paths. It would be painful. Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is from `typescript` side. VS code does suggest auto imports for Modules which are not in subfolder like `@angular/forms`, `@angular/core`, `@angular/common`. But not able to suggest for modules which reside inside a subfolder like `@angular/common/http`. See here `http` is inside `common`